# Job which I've commented out of config/sidekiq.yml is still running somehow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm not super familiar with Sidekiq, but my project has a `config/sidekiq.yml` file with some jobs listed.

I've made changes to this file, as well as commented some jobs out... yet whenever I run `bundle exec sidekiq` it seems as though the sidekiq process has no idea that `config/sidekiq.yml` had changed.

I'm seeing sidekiq trying to run a job which has since been renamed, and it's also attempting to run a job which I've commented out completely.

It seems `bundle exec sidekiq` is oblivious to the changes to `config/sidekiq.yml`?

I've rebooted the rails development server, as well as sidekiq, both at the same time, and tried `rake tmp:cache:clear`

I've also opened up the rails console and entered:

```
require 'sidekiq/api'
Sidekiq::Queue.all.each(&:clear)
```

I still seem to have zombie jobs trying to run.

Comment: The Sidekiq job queues are stored inside your Redis database, they don't go away when Sidekiq shuts down. Unless they completed or deleted there will still be jobs in the queues when Sidekiq starts. Use the [Sidekiq UI](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring) to look at your queues. It's possible you have them in retry queues.

Answer (score 1):

`Sidekiq::Queue` does not include your [retry queues](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#retries). You probably have jobs there as well.

Consider using [the Sidekiq UI](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring) to monitor the state of your queues.

Answer (score 0):

you could try `redis-cli FLUSHALL`

as for the Sidekiq UI:

```rb
# config/routes.rb
require "sidekiq/web"
authenticate :user, ->(user) { user.admin? } do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

will allow admin users to visit **/sidekiq** and see the retries that @Schwern was mentioning.

if you dont have an admin boolean yet:
`rails g migration AddAdminToUsers`
and this inside:

```rb
def change
  add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, null: false, default: false
end
```